Python command-line history with timestamps
Is there a way to record the time of each command? For example, hooking the interactive shell so that it writes the same content of ~/.python_history to ~/.python_history_timestamps but with timestamps?
I am keeping track of what I do during the day and putting into my calendar.
To help with backtracking I use the firefox history, zsh history, sent and draft email times, Dropbox activity, a vim autocommand writing all timestamps of all saved files to ~/.vimsavelog but if I spend 2 hours doing stuff in python interactive I can easily end up at the end of the day having no idea what I did on those two hours.
I would even like to have the kernel/filesystem record all filesaves in the folder Downloads, but that's another question.
Or is there a better way to achieve this kind of log? Ideally I would like precision down to 15 minutes.
I am aware of ~/.python_history, readline and ipython's %history -g but I have no clue of if and how one can add timestamps. I saw readline.set_pre_input_hook but it is not really clear to me what it does or how it works since it says that the hooks are called with no inputs.
